# PDF splitting on visual lines

Tags: pdf, ocr, edit, batch-processing

I am in need of information for the following problem:

**Context**: I have ringed folders with alot of songs in. The amount of songs in the folders has caused the rings in the paper to degrade. This would be solved if I got another ringed folder but I am now at the count of 2 and any more will be a hassle if I need to take them with me.

I am planning to scan all the pages to PDF. (Which hopefully will take the most time). The format of a page is shown in the picture. You always have  the number of a song with the chord in which it was written (now presented as title). When a song ends there will be a black line when it goes to the next one. And like this we have 2 columns per page.

[image: example image]

**Goal:** I want 1 pdf per song with a prefix XXX.pdf in which XXX the number is. Yes at the moment there are more then 700 songs.

**What I need:**

1. Split PDFs on middle black line
2. Concatenate the split PDFs  (multiple PDFs because songs can be printed over different PDFs)
3. Split on the horizontal lines to separate PDFs with the correct numbering
4. (Optional:) straighten out the PDFs so they are nicely straight

I have looked for programs that are able to batch process with OCR but have not found ones that are able to split on a visual line. That is why I would want to code this for myself/ open source community. So I am a programmer I know **OCR** exists but I have absolutely no experience with it. I have no clue where to start looking or with which programming language this would be possible. Any help is appreciated.

...

I will just start scanning my pages...

Comment: If the regions where the page is to be broken up remains constant, use an image editor, for example [this](http://www.irfanview.com/) and batch process the cropping of each PDF.

Comment: Thank you, in itself the horizontal regions differ. But the middle line does not so maybe I can use this program to split on the vertical lines.

Comment: You're welcome, if you work out a solution please do not forget to come back and post an answer to help the community.  If the middle line isn't different, use that as a start then group the resulant files as per lines 2-3 (group A) and lines 4-5 (group B) and process each group separately.